# pass php array to javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to get array from sql server using php , and parsing these array to javascript using ajax.
However , I have tried many solution by google , I can't get the array.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
    include 'Connect.php';
    $Store_int = $_GET['num'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `store` WHERE `Place_int` = " . $Store_int;

    mysqli_select_db($link, "web");
    $link->set_charset("utf8");
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $arr = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $p = (string)$row->Name;
        $arr[] = $p;
    }
    //print_r($arr);
    $jsonArr = json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $jsonArr;
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Array in php will encode and display:

```
["pen","pencil","apple","cat","dog"]
```

and the .js file

```
function getArr(store_int) {
    var jsArray = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: "fromSQL_store.php",
        data: {
            num: $("#store_int").val()
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(num);
            jsArray = JSON.parse(data.jsonArr);
        }, error: function (data) {
            alert("123");
        }
    });
    //alert(jsArray.length);
    return jsArray;
}
```

In .js , I will always get empty response(undefined) from php.
Because the ajax will answer "error" function..., and the error status is 200.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: As for your question, you need to also set JSON `Content-Type` header in PHP

Comment: @tereško thanks, I'll prevent the SQL injections after solve the problem.

Comment: @Zi-yanTseng you don't use this `store_int` parameter why is it there?

Comment: @2by2 hi , it will pass by outside . Ex: getArr("1");

Comment: the error status is 200

Comment: @Zi-yanTseng what are you going to use it for?

Comment: @2by2 In the fact , it's a little homework , and i have finished it by the other way. However , my teacher tells me "ajax" is important , I try my best on this way.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array will always return `undfined` as the `AJAX` call is async, your function returns `jsArray` before it is set. and You don't need `JSON.parse()` as you have defined `dataType` as `json` in your ajax call. Pass a function to your `getArr()` function and use your data in that function.

```
function getArr(store_int, outputFn){ // what do you use store_int for?
   $.ajax({
       url: "fromSQL_store.php",
       data: {
           num: $("#store_int").val()
       },
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           outputFn(data)
       },error: function(data){
           alert("123");
       }
   });
}
```

Then use it like

```
getArr('5', function (data) {
       console.log(data)
})
```

Console output

[image]

Comment: hello , I try it , and error again. And I change lots of the code in another way

Comment: unexpected token at position 0

Comment: yes , i have tried your code , and get the error response by errorThrown

Comment: hello , i find the problem , i include 'Connect.php' , and there is html code in the Connect.php. Hence , I can't parse the json , even though I've deleted the Html code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here. You are attempting to access `data.jsonArr` which is always undefined. The JSON data sent is actually embodied by `data` variable.

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(num);
    jsArray = JSON.parse(data.jsonArr); // Replace by jsArray = data;
}
```

NOTE, You might also need to specify that the MIME media type that is being outputted is JSON. Putting this at the top of your PHP script should solve your problem.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: hello , i finish it , and the result is the same . And some of my database data will be Garbled.

Comment: Thanks , i solve the garbled by adding charset=utf-8

Comment: @EyuelDK hi , i change the code in .js , i find the answer from ajax will error...

Comment: I'm no sure what the problem is then... if the ajax itself is throwing an error, i.e. the `error` callback is being called I'm kinda lost then. You should read the error on your PHP side for more information.